# I cannot see button on pop up window in C#

Tags: c#, button, popup, window

I cannot see the button on popup window. I have created a popup window and put a button on that window to close it, but can't actually close it. When I run the program, I cannot see the button. I can see only the popup window without button.

Here's the code to create button and pop up window (UcPopUpConfirm.ascx):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" 
            runat="server" 
            ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
            OnClick="Button1_Click1" 
            Text="Tamam" 
            CssClass="dx" 
            Font-Bold="True" 
            Font-Size="Large" 
            Width="87px" />
```

Here's the  code inside in button click handler:

```
public void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
      PopupControlContentControl1.Visible = false;
      Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Close.me()");
      return;    
}
```

Comment: Please give more additional details like partial mark-ups of your pop-up window

Comment: Could you have set it to invisible or hidden using CSS by accident?